# BigQuery Data.ErrorProto.Reason "stopped"

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm inserting data with `insertAll()` but `DataInsertAllRespone.InsertErrors` returns the same error of each row I have inserted.

The errors only give me the field

`**Data.ErrorProto.Reason** which contains: **"stopped"**`.

This is the method that call insertAll():

```
public bool InsertAll(BigqueryService s, String datasetId, String tableId, List<TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData> data)
{
    TabledataResource t = s.Tabledata;
    TableDataInsertAllRequest req = new TableDataInsertAllRequest()
    {
        Kind = "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
        Rows = data /*Posar aquí les files per pujar al BigQuery*/
    };
    TableDataInsertAllResponse response = t.InsertAll(req, projectId, datasetId, tableId).Execute();
    if (response.InsertErrors != null) return true;
    return false;
}
```

What happens? Why can't upload data?

**EDIT: ** I realize that if i upload less than 6 rows works correctly, but the row size  is about 1,6 Kb and the maximum row size is 20Kb.

Thanks,
Roger

Comment: Can you paste more of your code so we can reproduce?

Comment: thanks for sharing the solution too! (couldn't find the cause before you)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, a few days ago I found the solution. When you streaming data into BigQuery using insertAll() method, you can stream multiple rows at once. If one of these rows is wrong **Data.ErrorProto.Reason** contains message for this error, for example, "Can't convert value to string." and the other rows contain "stopped" in **Data.ErrorProto.Reason**.

If you ever see this error, probably you have inconsistencies in the rows format